# mysql query: query nested (?)

Tags: php, mysql

hi here's my data structure:

```
categories
id   name
----------------
1    dogs    
2    cats
3    birds

images
id   name   cat  datetime     views
---------------------------------------
1    dog1   1    2015-10-01   123
2    dog2   1    2015-10-02   45
3    cat1   2    2015-10-03   678
4    cat2   2    2015-11-01   901
5    cat3   2    2015-11-02   234
6    bird1  3    2015-12-03   456
```

i want to output:
all categories and each category should show:

- amount of images
- maximum amount of views
- date of latest image
- id of latest file

desired output:

```
cat  name     images  views   latest       id_latest
----------------------------------------------------
1    dogs     2       123     2015-10-02   5
2    cats     3       901     2015-11-02   4
3    birds    1       456     2015-12-03   6
```

my query so far:

```
Select
  categories.*,
  Count(images.id) As images,
  Sum(images.views) As views,
  Max(images.datetime) As latest

From
  categories 
  Left Join images On images.catid =  categories.id 
Group By
  categories.id
```

the problem is: how would i get the last field `id_latest`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t.*, i.id as imageID 
  from 
    (Select 
        categories.*,
        Count(images.id) As images,
        Sum(images.views) As views,
        Max(images.datetime) As latest
      From categories 
      Left Join 
        images 
        On images.catid =  categories.id 
      Group By categories.id
    ) t
  left join 
    images i 
    on i.`datetime`= latest
```

[example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94e0c/2)